# How to save the tensorflow model in .h5 format using tensorflow model checkpoints?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, python-3.5

I am working on tensorflow project. I have successfully train, test and make prediction using python flask. But in order to make prediction each time i have to again load full model using checkpoints. If I save the model .h5 format, I don't need to load the dataset to predict the datasets. I am don't know how to save the tensorflow model in .h5 format using checkpoints. If anybody know how to do, please help me or forward me any link if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can save and restore tensorflow models using `tf.train.Saver` class.
Although this doesn't store the models in `.h5` format.

You can refer to these sections for further clarity:
[Save](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#save_variables)
[Restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#restore_variables)

Hope this helps!